# How to Quickly Find Unused Part of the CSS and JS Codes in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using Chrome DevTools to analyze the code coverage of a page https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/5-methods-remove-highlighting-shading-word-document/

I get the following result:

[image]

I notice that there are some CSS files that have 98.1% and 99.7% unused rate, so I want to figure out what part is actually used. But these files are rather large, for example, ssba.css is 4000+ lines, and I can only see red vertical lines beside, but cannot find the green ones to indicate the used part. And it is rather time-consuming to scroll down one by one for a 4000+ line file. So, is there an easy way to jump to the first used part, then go to the next used part, etc.? Or in other word, quickly find the used parts easily?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome DevTools cannot actually edit your code for you, since it is located on a server (or in this case, your machine) which Chrome doesn't have access to. The best you can do is either automate it with an extension, script or other tool.

Comment: Thank you. I don't want to edit the code via DevTools, I just want to find the unused code parts easily, when facing thousands of lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Chrome's "Css Used" extension for css codes. This extension gives you only used css codes in chrome dev tools. I don't know anything about JS.